# PHP json_encode is returning as array string, but is not converting to array in JavaScript properly

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I make a $.post request to submit data and return invalid data. Here is the $.post request:

```
    $('#submitAll').click(function(){
        $.post("php/entries/submitAndReload.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){

            alert(data); // alerts: "[[“0”, “0”,””,””, “0”, “0”, “0”, “0”,”No Style”]]"
            dataObject.dataArray = data;

            $.post("php/entries/stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){
                $('#stageArea').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

`dataObject.dataArray` is a double array and `alert(data)` alerts what looks like the proper format for the subsequent $.post request, but the output from the 2nd $.post request looks like I pass in the following array:`[[ "[" ]]`. The first field gets a `"["` and no other fields get data.

I'm not sure what's going on here and how to properly store the returned `data` into `dataObject.dataArray`

**What's going on here?**

Comment: `data` is a JSON string, not an array. You need to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this line:

```
dataObject.dataArray = data;
```

To this:

```
dataObject.dataArray = JSON.parse( data );
```

You need to parse JSON, untill parsing it is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

Add `dataType` argument to `$.post`.

When set as `'json'` jQuery knows to parse it to object/array from json string

```
$.post(url, postData, function(data){
     // handling code
     alert($.type(data)); //"array"

},'json');
```

If you set proper content Type header at server also it helps

Reference: [$.post docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)